# Creating a list of deduplicated lists based on matches in loop? - Python, Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to accomplish this with Pycharm 2017.1.3., Openpyxl 2.4.7, and Excel 2016.

Here is a smaller version of my data set, for starters:

SHEET1:

```
| partID |    keywordcategory |keyword|
| 4849348| searchkeyword1     |Hobbock
| 4849348| searchkeyword1     |Lentso*  
| 4849348| searchkeyword2     |Lentso|           
| 4849348| searchkeyword3     |LENTSO-EIEMR                            | 
| 4849348| searchkeyword3     |Hobbock         
| 4849346| searchkeyword1     |protein
| 4849346| searchkeyword3     |ion
```

The result I want to achieve is, for each unique part number, to:

A. Get a list of the unique search terms at each keyword category, AND

B. A combined list of each part number's keywords across all keywordcategories. Heres an example of what I'd love to end up with:

```
| partID |searchkeyword1  |searchkeyword2|searchkeyword3|combined
| 4849348| Hobbock;Lentso*|Lentso        |LENTSO-EIMER  |Hobbock;Lentso*;
                                                        |Lentso; 
                                                        |LENTSO-EIMER    
| 4849346| protein        |              |ion           |protein;ion
```

This is what I've been working on so far, but it doesn't seem to be creating new lists at each row.
    import openpyxl

```
print('Opening file...')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('keywords.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
maxRow1 = sheet1.max_row + 1
maxRow2 = sheet2.max_row + 1
print('Processing...')

for rowNum in range(1, maxRow2):
for col in sheet1.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=2, max_col=2, max_row=1000):
    for cell in col:
        keywordlist = []
        if cell.value == sheet2.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value:
            if sheet1.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value == 16985323:
                #if sheet1.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value not in keywordlist and 'None' not in sheet1.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value:
                keywordlist.append(sheet1.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value + ';')
                sheet2.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value = str(keywordlist)
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Charlie's help has gotten me a lot further than I was!

The issue I'm having now is that when I try to use the defaultdict(list) on my actual project, it doesn't seem to be removing the duplicates. 
It works when I try the examples I've found online, but not with my actual project.

I think the issue is likely how I'm generating the dictionary. This is what I'm doing now:

```
for rownum in range(1,maxRow):
    partnum = str(sheet1.cell(row=rownum, column=1).value)
    keyword1 = str(sheet1.cell(row=rownum, column=3).value)


s = [(partnum,keyword1)]
    print(s)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)
```

If you have any help you might be able to offer, I would greatly appreciate it! Thankyou!

Comment: There's no need to nest `ws.iter_cols()` in a row loop.

Comment: Have a look at the pandas package. DataFrames can do everything you want (I think) within a few lines of code. In case you encounter issues reading the Excel file with the pandas package then use openpyxl to read the data and write some code to put it into a Dataframe.

Comment: @Elmex80s yeah, essentially denormalising the data is required so that it can be cast as desired. But it might be simplest to do this directly in Python.

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates you might want to use a `set` instead of a `list` as sets never contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably tackle this in two stages: first build a dictionary of the search terms: I've written elsewhere on how to do this but you'll want to extend it for your purposes. The easiest way would be to have a dictionary like `{1: ['Hobbock' 'Lentso'], 2:['Lentso'],…}` use `defauldict` with the default of a list for this.

You can then loop through the list or dictionary of parts to write the rows.

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks so much for your help! I edited my original post with the issue I'm having now with the defaultdict function, if you have a spare second could you look at my edit? Thanks so much!